# SSMS 2017 Export SCOPED CONFIGURATION

Tags: ssms, configuration

I reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch.

I'm trying to get SSMS options setup the way I like them. When I r-click a DB, then `Tasks->GenerateScripts`, the result doesn't contain `SCOPED CONFIGURATION` lines anymore. I checked the various SSMS scripting options and don't see one specifically for `SCOPED CONFIGURATION`.

- Does anyone have ideas on why GenerateScripts doesn't include `SCOPED CONFIGURATION` lines?

SSMS 17.9.1 SQL Server 14.0.2002.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am using SSMS 18.0, it is scripting out The database scoped configuration i just changed as a test when scripting out the full (azure sql db) database

Comment: Are you by any chance scripting for a server version lower than 2016?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @CR241 that is probably it, I'd say you could post it as the answer when Greg validates this.

Comment: I was scripting for 2017. I also tried Azure DB (our production DBs).

Comment: Maybe too late if you've already reinstalled, but you can export your SSMS settings to a `.vssettings` file, which you can import in another environment.

Answer (score 2):

> why GenerateScripts doesn't include SCOPED CONFIGURATION lines?

**Because When scripting objects, DB Scoped configuration that has default values are omitted.**

Check [SQL Server Management Studio - Changelog (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) for more information.

SSMS 18.0 (preview 4) -> Bug fixes -> Object Scripting

Comment: I'll try the v18 preview. This would explain things... Thank you